# How to remove a keychain in OS X?

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm using Mac 10.11.3
I installed Card Reader for PIV and mess something and now I have 'wrong' Keychain CAC-000... It is not one that I need.
I have to get rid of it and setup another Keychain.
I tried to 'Reset My default Keychain' option but it did not remove this one.

How could I remove this one?

[image: This is a Keychain that I want to delete]

Comment: Answer: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password)

Answer (score 1):

I hate keychain issues...

In Finder use key-combo Command+Shift+G and paste in: ~/Library/Keychains/

Rename the CAC keychain file with .bkp extension at the end if you don't want to delete it. This should remove the file from your keychain.

If it is not gone in Keychain Access after that right click and delete it and select Delete References and Files.

The 'login' keychain is your default, if you want to reset it then go to the Keychain access preferences and select reset from there.

Then restart your Mac.

Comment: I am all set now.My problems was that I tried to delete it from terminal and it did not work. Deleting from Finder solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad to here it!