# Deleting an app’s data from the iOS Keychain, or resetting the Keychain entirely

Tags: ios, keychain

I installed an app that stores a persistent identifier in the iOS keychain, even after uninstalling and reinstalling it. This really bugs me. Is there a way to delete said app's data from the Keychain, or worst-case resetting the entire iOS Keychain, without resetting the device completely?

**Note**: I'm not talking about the iCloud Keychain, but the on-device keychain that apps can store small bits of data in.

Answer (score 1):

No. Application sandboxing means these entries are stored in a way other third party apps cannot reach into iOS sandbox library files to observe or clean. I suppose you could jailbreak the device if you had to purge things.

I totally get the annoyance - it’s your data and your device, so it’s frustrating to not be able to control it, especially since cookies and local store is a privacy issue persisting data when an app is removed.

The only practical solution short of a jailbreak into third party app sandboxes is to use apps that store items in an iCloud synced keychain so a Mac can clean and observe.

Comment: Could you explain how sandboxing is related to Apple not providing the appropriate functionality in iOS? I was pretty sure that built-in apps can do whatever they want (with appropriate support from the system / kernel). As far as I know, Safari has different kernel-level flags in its process, for example.

Comment: @cubuspl42 what do you mean appropriate functionality?

Comment: I mean the functionality of managing (viewing, removing, ...) the keychain, let's say something like a simplified version of macOS "Keychain Access" app, possibly as an advanced section in the iOS system Settings app.

Comment: Ah yes @cubuspl42 the sandbox does not exist on macOS for third party apps, just iOS / watchOS / tvOS - the only thing Apple engineered is cloud keychains you could use the macOS tool to see and change data shared between the OS.

Comment: Here's a description of [sandboxing on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox), but that's not the point. Maybe there's some misunderstanding here? The OP, as I read it, asks about a human-accessible way to delete a Keychain entry on iOS (possibly in Settings app, or any other way). Not a way to clear it programatically from an unrelated third party app, or anything. I'm not saying it's a big deal, but I cannot see how sandboxing is connected to this topic.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the correct answer is "It's not possible, because Apple chose not to provide provide such functionality in any system app", not "It's not possible because of sandboxing". If it's not the case, I'd be willing to understand it, because I'm interested in this subject.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve updated the answer to hopefully help you and others…

Comment: @cubuspl42 I agree with you. This answer is confusing and misleading. I guess the author didn't understand the basics of ios keychain and sandbox.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this link? I'm pretty sure this is the answer you're looking for, this link tells you to;

> 1) Open the Mac Keychain. Click Finder > Go > Utilities > Keychain
>   Access.
>
> 2) In Keychain Access, select the Passwords category on the left to
>   review the list of sites and services for which you've saved a
>   password.
>
> 3) Right-click the service you want to edit/remove, then left-click
>   Delete.

https://answers.uillinois.edu/68546

If you're looking to get rid of sandbox,

> 1) Quit sandbox as well as its related process(es) if they are still
>   running.
>
> 2) Launch Finder on your Mac, and click Applications in the Finder
>   sidebar.
>
> 3) Search for sandbox in the /Applications folder, then drag its icon
>   to the Trash icon located at the end of the Dock, and drop it there.
>   Also, you can right-click/control click sandbox icon and then choose
>   to Move to Trash option from the sub-menu.
>
> 4) If prompted, enter the administrator password and hit OK to allow
>   the change.
>
> 5) Choose Finder > Empty Trash from the Menu bar. Or choose
>   right-click Trash icon, choose Empty Trash, and Empty Trash again in
>   the pop-up dialogue.

https://macuninstallguides.com/remove-sandbox-on-mac.html

> (Note, you **don't** have to install any apps to remove it)

If you want to reset the entire keychain, I recommend that you take a look at the answer on this page.

[How do I delete or fix my Keychain after changing my password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password)

Comment: This answer is unfortunately incorrect. The top part of the answer is for macOS, not iOS - so it doesn't help here. The second part is a guide you found on a "fake" web page - it has not relation to actual reality - and makes no sense at all. You cannot, ofcourse, "uninstall" the sandbox like that. The third part of the answer is again for macOS, and not iOS.

Comment: Totally misleading and waste of time to read it.