# Mac Keychain problems after deleting .AppleSetupDone

Tags: keychain, mojave

So one day I decided to restart my macbook pro mid 2012 13" but then i noticed my user is gone and it is asking me for a name and password, so i tried to type my username and password yet it was wrong. So what i did was delete .AppleSetupDone and after I delete that everything was good and I was able to setup a new admin user and after that I'm having issues with my keychain like let's say opera asks me if i want to save the password or not and if i hit save it actually doesn't save it next is everytime i log back in i am no longer connected to the wifi and everytime i connect it will say it cannot find a keychain that can store something so i click reset to defaults (smth like that) and then the window just dissapeared. So what I did was go to keychain access > Preferences and clicked reset my default keychains but then it shows unable to obtain authorization for this operation and since keychain first aid is gone already I no longer know what to do

Comment: wall of text please take a breath and think about what you need to tell us and think about where sentences start and end and capital letters at the start of sentences and then come to a conclusion rather than just keep typing what you thought of next whether it was relevant to the last thought or not

Comment: Please use multiple paragraphs and use periods so it doesn't look like a wall of text, like Tetsujin said. It will be a lot easier to understand for anyone answering your question.

Comment: Did you use the same or a similar name(s) for the new account as the old one? Are you now using the new account or the old one, and does the old one even show up at all (e.g. at the login screen or in Users & Groups preferences)?

Answer (score 1):

As @Tetsujin pointed out your question a *a wall of text* and is difficult to read.

Although you reset your user password/created a new one the Keychain is encrypted using the old password.

Take a look a the following articles, they should solve your problem.

- [Reset Keychain Password](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/if-you-need-to-update-your-keychain-password-kyca2429/mac)
- [If you keep getting prompted to enter your keychain password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609)

Also take a look at this AskDifferent answer describing some possible fixes.

[How do I delete or fix my Keychain after changing my password?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/how-do-i-delete-or-fix-my-keychain-after-changing-my-password)

**If none of these work, please edit your question to clarify your issue.**